# Spark structured streaming broadcast join hint

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using Spark 2.2.0, with following SQL statement, broadcast hint does not seem work.

```
// table dim is some static table
// table s is some stream table
spark.sql("select /*+ BROADCAST(dim) */ s.a, dim.b from s left outer join dim
 on s.b = dim.b")
```

And I check the physical plan, it shows that the plan is the `SortMergeJoin`.

Comment: Is the when the size of one side dim table is below spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold? Its 10485760 (10 MB) by default.You can run 
"ANALYZE TABLE <tableName> COMPUTE STATISTICS noscan "
if its a Hive Metastore tables.